# Sabre API integration, do I have to mention Sabre somewhere in my website?

Tags: sabre

I'm trying to create a hotel booking and hotel reservation website, My client requires that no API name should be visible anywhere in the website nor in the fetched results, so just show the hotels names and reserve smoothly without saying anything about Sabre or about any other provider or travel agancy.

I tried searching Sabre documentation but was not able to find if this is required in my website or no and if a provider name will be written automatically in the fetched results.

Would be thankful if someone helps me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's a requirement from Sabre. I would advise to reach your account team with such questions.